# Auto complete with tab not working in IPython

Tags: auto-complete-mode, ipython

I installed Emacs for Python ([from this github repo](https://github.com/gabrielelanaro/emacs-for-python)) on my Emacs 24.5.1. When I start an IPython shell, auto-complete with tab doesn't work. Instead, the tab key just insert four spaces. But if I press Enter leaving those spaces, the auto-complete suggestions appear in the buffer.

For example:

```
In [6]: import numpy as np

In [7]: x = np.arr

np.array         np.array_equal   np.array_repr    np.array_str
np.array2string  np.array_equiv   np.array_split

np.array         np.array_equal   np.array_repr    np.array_str
np.array2string  np.array_equiv   np.array_split

In [8]:
```

After `x = np.arr`, I pressed tab twice before Enter, and then all suggestions appeared at once.

If I press `M-/`, Emacs tries to auto-complete the name, but it doesn't show me all options. In the example above, I would have to press it many times to cicle through all available completions.

My `.emacs` file is as follows:

```
(load-file "/home/erickrf/.emacs.d/emacs-for-python/epy-init.el")
(epy-setup-ipython)

;; disable auto parenthesis completion
(setq skeleton-pair nil)

(put 'erase-buffer 'disabled nil)
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19972936/no-tab-completion-for-ipython-in-emacs-textmode) is a similar problem. I tried the solution in the accepted answer, but it didn't work for me. Whenever I pressed tab, Emacs would show the error message `Symbol's value as variable is void: python-shell-completion-complete-or-indent`

Comment: You probably need to `(require 'python)` before you do that, at least make sure that: https://github.com/gabrielelanaro/emacs-for-python/blob/2f284d14d03c69adce1dcac9ef3fb297ee95dfa9/extensions/python.el#L1785 you have this line in your `python.el`. Actually, wait, I don't know if this extends to Python shell, but you are trying to do that in the shell, right, not in a *.py file?

Comment: Yes, in the IPython shell.